# Are Kafka topic changes concurrent?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic in Kafka (0.10 if it is important). Several producers are writing to this topic. Now I want to change this topic in some way:

- To increase replication factor
- To reassign partitions between available brokers

Are these operations concurrent? Meaning can producers continue to write data into Kafka while they are in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, the producers can continue to write data to Kafka.